# Compilation error with a 3 rd party jar in spring boot maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot project in Eclipse. I have added an external 3rd party jar in project build path which is not a maven dependency. Now I am able to import 2 classes from the jar that I need and I wrote my some implementation. Now when i am trying to build my maven project with `clean install`, I am getting compilation failure with the same 2 imports that I have used.  The error says : package does not exist.

Am I missing anything in the configuration part ? I have added the jar as external jar in project build path. Then I have clean compiled the project. is there anything else that i need to do to use a 3 rd party jar in a spring boot project which is build by maven ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a local repo like below :

```
    <repository>
        <id>in-project</id>
        <name>Local Project Repo</name>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/lib/</url>
    </repository>
```

Then add the dependency as below :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>abcd</groupId>
        <artifactId>efgh</artifactId>
        <version>1.X.O</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add this external jar as a dependency to make the maven build work.

There is a system scope for that purpose. Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath><path_to_jar>/your.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your solution. This works ! But I was going through some pages where it is said to avoid using system scope. So I have used a local repo and then added the dependency without the system scope and I have removed the jar from build path. It got compiled successfully. I have provided another answer below. But you are quite experienced so I would be glad to have a suggestion from you which is better to use and why should we avoid the other.

Comment: No... 2 more ppl are there.. Ultimately we plan to move the jar in the actual repo that we use... this being a temporary workaround ...

Comment: That's what I wanted to suggest. IMHO both temporary solutions are ok